# Function that does `M-x replace-regexp` or `M-x occur` with a fixed pattern and replacement strings

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, string, occur

I often use `M-x replace-regexp` and `M-x occur` with some fixed regexp pattern and replacement string on many files.

Doing it manually by opening each file in an Emacs buffer and hitting the keys is very tedious. I was wondering how to write an Elisp function to use as a script, which I can apply to each file?

Comment: See also `multi-occur`.

Comment: You could write a macro that opens files from `dired`, edits them, and goes back to it. You can move by marked files in `dired` with `M-{` and `M-}`.

Comment: If you are working on multiple files, I'd recommend going to the shell, and using sed/awk/perl/python/whatever.

Answer (score 2):

One way this can be accomplished is by using `dired`.  Here's an article from Xah Lee on how to use `dired` to find and replace across files: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/find_replace_inter.html

In short, open `dired` and place the cursor on the directory in which you wish to find and replace.  Press `Q` to start up the query replace prompt.  Enter your search pattern and replacement and Emacs will open an `*xref*` buffer containing all the matches.  It will also begin going through each match, opening the buffer, and querying if you'd like to replace it.  From the article:

```
Type y to replace current highlighted occurrence. (emacs will then jump to next one.)
Type n to skip.
Type Ctrl+g to abort the whole find/replace.
Type ! to replace all occurrences in current file without more asking.
Type N to skip all possible replacement for rest of the current file.
Type Y to do the replacement on all files without further asking.
```

Answer (score 2):

For `replace-regexp` in many files, select the files in [Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) and press `Q` to run [`dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Operating-on-Files.html#index-search-and-replace-in-multiple-files-_0028in-Dired_0029-3432). See also the [FAQ entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-text-across-multiple-files.html).

For the equivalent of `occur` in many files, you can use `A` ([`dired-do-find-regexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Operating-on-Files.html#index-search-multiple-files-_0028in-Dired_0029-3427)) in Dired. Another solution that doesn't use Dired is the [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html#Grep-Searching) functions and its variants, where you select files with shell wildcards. Variants include `grep-find` to search in subdirectories recursively, and (in recent Emacs versions) `zgrep` to search in compressed files. You can edit the command line to use other shell commands.

For the equivalent of `occur` in multiple buffers (i.e. files that are already open), there's [`multi-occur-in-matching-buffers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html#index-multi_002doccur_002din_002dmatching_002dbuffers-1041). There are other variants that require entering buffer or file names one by one, but I find those inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using rgrep to find the regexp, then in the results buffer enable wgrep-mode (M-x wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode, or C-c C-p).

This will allow you to edit (replace) the regexp directly from within the results buffer, bypassing the need to open each file individually.

When the replacement is complete, press C-c C-c to apply the changes to the files, and M-x wgrep-save-all-buffers to save the changes.

- Chris

Comment: n.b. `wgrep` is a third-party library you will need to install (and it's great, so you should do that).